# About GROUP BY in Django

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have some question:

```
# models.py
class someinfo(models.Model):
    data1 = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='data1')
    data2 = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='data2')
    data_pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='data_pubdate')
    people = models.ForeignKey(Drive, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='people')
```

data table have:

```
# row data
data1    data2        data_pubdate                people
7777129  23232        2017-05-18 05:04:08.377     9   
158160   4573279      2017-05-18 05:04:08.737     8
158200   5709307      2017-05-18 05:04:08.787     6
10073    11612        2017-05-18 05:04:19.727     6
2458     5245466      2017-05-18 05:04:19.727     4
2458     5245466      2017-05-18 05:04:19.724     4
14879    9727         2017-05-18 05:04:19.897     7
...etc
```

I want select data1 and data2 from new data_pubdate in each people, like this table:

```
# select data
data1    data2        data_pubdate                people
7777129  23232        2017-05-18 05:04:08.377     9   
158160   4573279      2017-05-18 05:04:08.737     8
10073    11612        2017-05-18 05:04:19.727     6
2458     5245466      2017-05-18 05:04:19.727     4   
14879    9727         2017-05-18 05:04:19.897     7
```

So...What should I do?

P.S. django version is "1.10", database is "MSSQL server 2012"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be:

```
SomeInfo.objects.annotate(
    last_pubdate=Max('people__someinfo__data_pubdate')
).filter(last_pubdate=F('data_pubdate'))
```

Comment: Your suggestion is wonderful useful. I will try to understand this principle.